# Pyspark: Input_filename() returns empty string when reading json.gz file

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, aws-glue, aws-glue-spark

I am trying to get filenames(file format:json.gz) using input_filename() function in pyspark. Below is the code:

```
df.withColumn("source_file",sql_f.element_at(sql_f.split(sql_f.input_file_name(), "/"), -1)
```

It returns an empty string. Below is the screenshot:
[image]

I have tried to get the filename by simply using input_file_name() as well:

```
df.withColumn("source_file",sql_f.input_file_name())
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what are you reading ? a json file or a sql db ? `Creates a string column for the file name of the current Spark task`

Comment: I am reading a json.gz file